# Msw not able to intercept tRPC requests but working fine for fetch calls (jest + rtl)

Tags: reactjs, react-query, msw, trpc

I'm trying to test out react components which are using tRPC apis. I'm having a very difficult time trying to understand where I'm going wrong - thanks to the lib's author's refusal to document it.

I'm using MSW to create a mock server, intercept requests and mock response. While it's able to intercept fetch requests from my test function, it's not able to do the same for tRPC requests.

I'm using T3 stack and here's what I've got so far:

**tRPC Wrapper:**

```js
export const Trpc = createTRPCReact<AppRouter>();

const trpcClient = Trpc.createClient({
    transformer: superjson,
    links: [
        httpBatchLink({
            url: `http://localhost:${process.env.PORT ?? 3000}/api/trpc`,
            headers: () => ({
                "x-csrf-token": "fake-csrf-token",
            }),
        }),
    ],
});

const queryClient = new QueryClient({
    defaultOptions: { queries: { staleTime: Infinity } },
});

export const Wrapper = ({ children }: { children: ReactNode }) => {
    return (
        <Trpc.Provider client={trpcClient} queryClient={queryClient}>
            <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>{children}</QueryClientProvider>
        </Trpc.Provider>
    );
};
```

**My Unit test file - login.test.tsx**:

```js
const handlers = [
    rest.all("*", () => {
        console.log("request coming");
    }),
];

describe("LoginForm", () => {
      const trpcServer = setupServer(...handlers);

      beforeAll(() => {
        trpcServer.listen({
            onUnhandledRequest: "error",
        });
    });

    afterAll(() => {
        trpcServer.close();
    });

    afterEach(() => {
        trpcServer.resetHandlers();
    });

      // this should be called but it's not
      trpcServer.events.on("request:start", () => {
        console.log("request came");
      });

      it("renders VerifyOtpForm after sending OTP", async () => {
        const onLoginComplete = jest.fn();
        const { getByTestId, getByPlaceholderText } = render(<LoginForm onLoginComplete={onLoginComplete} />, {
            wrapper: Wrapper,
        });
        const sendOtpForm = getByTestId("send-otp-form");

        // await fetch("http://google.com");

        await waitFor(async () => {
            const usernameField = getByPlaceholderText("Enter your email");
            fireEvent.change(usernameField, { target: { value: "test@yahoo.com" } });
            fireEvent.submit(sendOtpForm); // this fires trpc.send_otp_procedure.mutate();
        });

        // expect(startTimerMock).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

My `jest.setup.js` file:

```js
import "@testing-library/jest-dom";

// mocks fetch implementation
import "whatwg-fetch";
```

Comment: Please try calling `server.listen()` either in the global test setup or on the root scope of your test module, not nested in `describe()`. Does that produce any change?

Comment: @kettanaito It didn't make any difference, not sure why should it. Anyways, I think the problem is specific to the t3 stack that I'm using. I'm not able figure out how to mock the tRPC api instance - `createTRPCNext`. Based on the setup above, when I console log `api` in my component - it says `[Function: noop]` - not sure why that is :(

Comment: It could because Jest controls when to call "describe" and "beforeAll", and those calls may be deferred in a way that obstructs MSW from proper module patching to enable request interception.

Comment: https://github.com/c-ehrlich/msw-trpc-example/blob/main/src/components/greeting.test.tsx